# Run Shell Script after click on button - YAD

Tags: command-line, gui, button

I have three shell scripts and I would like to run each script after click on button in yad - lets say - I have one yad session with three buttons - if I click on one button I will open 1. script - second button open 2. script and so on.. See my example bellow -

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(yad --width 100 --height 100 --title "Choose the Shell Script" \
    --text="  Please enter analysis details:" \
    --button="ShellScript1:2" \
    --button="ShellScript2:3" \
    --button="ShellScript3:3" \
    --button="Cancel:1" \
    --on-top \
    --center \
)

ret=$?
[[ $ret -eq 1 ]] && exit 0
```

Thank you for any idea or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add condition:

```
ret=$?

[[ $ret -eq 1 ]] && exit 0

if [[ $ret -eq 2 ]]; then

      /path/to/shell/1.sh
fi

if [[ $ret -eq 3 ]]; then

    /path/to/shell/2.sh

fi
```

Comment: To write a good answer, please add some explanations about what you changed and why.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives: 
1. You could use case instead of if like this:

```
case $ret in
    1) /path/to/script1 ;;
    2) /path/to/script2 ;;
    3) /path/to/script3 ;;
esac
```

2. You could alternativelly call the scripts directly from each button, without the need to manipulate the $? return code using this synthax:

   --button="ShellScript1:bash /path/to/script1.sh"

In my similar script with yad list this works fine:

```
yad --list --width=800 --height=600 --center \
    --button="Display":"/home/gg/Tests/yadabout.sh" --button="Cancel":0  \
    --column "ID" --column "File" \
    --column "Exec" "${list[@]}")
```

Difference:
When you assign an exit code/id to each button, after a button press yad returns it's value to the variable (files in your code) and the yad dialog exits.

If instead a button id you assign a command to run (case 2 above) then yad dialog remains on screen and does not exit. 
But in this mode there is not a yad return value , and thus you can not parse the selection from the yad dialog to this external command/script (not 100% sure, but i have not found any way to do it yet).

Comment: Thank you so much George for your help and helpful advice.

Answer (score -1):

To elaborate on the previous response:

```
processes=$(yad --width 100 --height 100 --title "Chose Process" --text="Select" --button="Run Cmd":1 --on-top --center)
ret=$?
if [[ $ret -eq 1 ]]; then
  /path/process.sh
fi
```